# Links in static block don't show or work

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

In my category I call a static block to left sidebar from category custom update XML

```
 <reference name="left">
       <block type="cms/block" name="kat_maerke" before="-"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>kat_maerke</block_id></action></block>
```

When I add links in the block "**kat_maerke**" it does not even show or work in frontpage left sidebar

Block shows the link code - but nothing on frontpage

```
<h2 class="filter-title" style="text-align: center;">Saturday Night Sweater</h2>
```

[image]

How to solve this??? Is there anything that blocking the link?
Please help - Thanx

Comment: Block code
<h2 class="filter-title" style="text-align: center;">Saturday Night Sweater</h2>
<p><a href="https://www.uldtraaden.dk/saturday-night-sweater"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/saturday-night-sweater.jpg"}}" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /></a></p>

Comment: above comment is your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

No, its the code in the Block with link.
But there is no image link, when I go to frontpage.
I think something blocks the link. I have tried in different browsers,  but the problem is still there - No link

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add this is in comment section of your question. You can also edit your question and can add there too but not here because its for posting answer only. Good luck.